# Set multiple URLs to return 410 apache

Tags: apache-2.4

I've already set multiple urls to give 410 redirects

```
Redirect 410 "/example-url"
```

However I have to edit multiple files to achieve this for many others URLs, is there a more elegant solution where, for example my 3x conf files can source these URLs from a single .txt file and that way reduce the clutter inside the conf files itself?

I considered LocationMatch but these urls do not match in any case and I would have to adjust the regex each time a new url needs to be set to 410.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue, where I placed all my redirections inside this file

```
gone_redirections.conf
```

and then included them with

```
Include conf.d/gone_redirections.conf
```